# I need to appear specific screens to specific users (not all ) in flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a complete app with flutter and joined with firebase because my app has a login page

But I need to appear specific screens to specific users (not all ) 
Just who I choose him ( like to make him admins and have specific profiles )

In my firebase, I have all my user 
Also, I collected the admins to the specific collection but how I can give him special screens in the app?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show different screens to different people, I am assuming you want to have a set extra screen for admins that test users cannot access? If so, you can make another Widget class(or .dart file, however you structure your code) and basically check if they are located in the admin branch, or have the subbranch of admin, and if they do, take them to the extra screen over the normal one.

Code (Replace with your values, the admin var would be known from a simple query):

```
if (admin){
    Navigator.push(context, adminClassName);
} else {
    Navigator.push(context, normalClassName);
}
```

Hope it helps!